# Send Message From Thread Created by Activity A to Activity B

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I currently have a `thread/AsyncTask` that I start in `Activity A`. Before that `AsyncTask` is started though, `Activity A` makes an object which takes in `Activity A's` `Context` so it can instantiate a `NotificationCompat.Builder`. The object uses this builder to make/show a notification.

This object is then passed to the AsyncTask as the `AsyncTask` is created and started. This allows the `AsyncTask` to update the object (and the notification) with its progress.

Once the `AsyncTask` has been started though, `Activity A` calls `finish()`, and the activity that started it, `Activity B`, resumes. What I would now like to happen is to have the object send/attempt to send a message to `Activity B` once the AsyncTask has said it is 100% complete. How can I achieve this?

PS: let me know if a picture would make the scenario more clear.

Comment: I think you could work with `startActivityForResult()`, if `Activity B` starts `Activity A` and requires its result.

Comment: It's not that `Activity B` requires the result of `Activity A`, it's more that once the task finishes, I want to refresh `Activity B`. `Activity A` is responsible for letting the user create & then upload new content (the AsyncTask does the uploading), while `Activity B` is a way to browse uploaded content. Using `startActivityForResult()` would be great if I forced `Activity A` to not `finish()` until the upload was complete, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: If you simply want to restart `Activity B`, use `Intent` & `Bundle` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: If the user is in a different `Activity` when the `intent` is sent from the object, would that suddenly make `Activity B` appear in the foreground?

Comment: @rolledback Any activity doesn't appear in the "foreground" by itself, unless you call `startActivity()`

Comment: So are you suggesting I use say...`broadcastIntent()` to send the intent then? (looking at the `Intent` documentation, that appears to be what I want)

Comment: @rolledback no no.... You only need to make a `callback`. If you are not familiar with call backs search for them.

Comment: @rustedbrain, ok I think I found a good [tutorial](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Service/Downloader) that shows how I can do that. I'll try out the solution and if it works I'll come back and detail it here. Otherwise, I'll give `broadcastIntent()` a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing up my own answer both because it was the result of discussion that happened in the comments of my question, and so there is a thorough overview of what I did for a solution.

I ended up going with callbacks as suggested by rusted brain. It is important to note that I am referring to the use of `android.os.Handler` to create a callback, not the callback pattern that is commonly used with things such as buttons. Anyway, onto the solution.

Step 1 was to set up a handler in `Activity B`:

```
messageHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        refreshList();
    }
};
```

Whatever is in handleMessage is what will be called when a message is sent to the handler.

Step 2 is to send a `android.os.Messenger` object to `Activity A`. This can easily be done with the `Intent`used to start `Activity A`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumGalleryActivity.this, CreateNewPhotoHuntActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("callbackMessenger", new Messenger(messageHandler));
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CREATE_NEW_PHOTO_HUNT);
```

Now, any messages sent by the `android.os.Messenger` will go to our `android.os.Handler`.

Step 3, the final step is to create a `android.os.Message` from the `android.os.Messenger` which can be sent back to the handler. In the context of my question, this is done inside of the object that controls updating the progress of the notification:

```
if(totalProgress >= 100) {
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Upload complete! ");
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    Message msg = Message.obtain();

    msg.arg1 = 1;

    try {
        callbackMessenger.send(msg);
    }
    catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
        Log.d(Constants.UploadProgressNotificationTag, e1.toString());
    }
}
```

So yep that's it. Feel free to comment if you have a Q or if you see a mistake in what I've posted. Also, I think using `Broadcasts` would also solve this issue, but that would require a bit more time/effort to implement. Thank you to everyone who suggested a solution!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have understood your question `Activity A` is started from `Activity B`. You can start A from B via `startActivityForResult` then rather finishing A when AsyncTask starts you `finish()` A when 100% task is loaded by AsyncTask and send result to A. You can implement callback interface to send result to Activity A from AsyncTask. Now call `finish()` to Activity A with `setResult()` and pass the result in intent to Activity B.

Comment: This is what I was previously was doing, but I'd prefer to let the user go back to `Activity B` while the task runs. See my reply to Amy's comment on the question.

Comment: Alright if you can make your Activity B launch with "singleinstance" it will be in new task with only activity. After AsyncTask completes just sed intent to Activity B since it is only activity in that task it will always receive the intent and will always be on top of stack.

Comment: I think this is what Amy was suggesting above, and so the follow up question I presented to her I'll ask you as well. If the user is in a different `Activity` when the `intent` is sent from the object, would that suddenly make `Activity B` appear in the foreground?

Comment: use taskmode "singleTop" with Activity B which states that 
 if there already is an Activity instance with the same type at the top of stack in the caller Task, there would not be any new Activity created, instead an Intent will be sent to an existed Activity instance through onNewIntent() method. 
You have to handle both onCreate() and onNewIntent() to make it works for all the cases.
Read more here http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en
Also read "singleTask" but in that case Activity B is promoted to top of Task but all other activities get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onPostExecute() method of the AsyncTask.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyObject> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do whatever you need to do
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MyObject myObject) {
        myObject.sendMessage(activityB);
    }
}
```

Note that onPostExecute() runs on the main UI thread, so it will be able to handle UI updates.

Comment: Right, but what method/technique/system/etc. should I actually use to send the message? I have the part where the object is told that the task is complete down, just not the sending of the message.

Comment: @rolledback you can create a `callback` or `interface` and when the task is complete, you tell your callback method to go and inform the listeners.